# display child elements of expandable listview from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, expandable

I want to populate expandable listview "child elements" to sqlite database, 
after user add elements to sqlite, it displays in child of expandable listview,
I want the parent to be static "not from database, just child",

```
private void fillData() {
    Cursor mGroupsCursor;
    mGroupsCursor = mHelper.fetchGroup();
    startManagingCursor(mGroupsCursor);
    mGroupsCursor.moveToFirst();

    ExpandableListView elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    madapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(mGroupsCursor, MainActivity.this,
            R.layout.list_group,                     // Your row layout for a group
            R.layout.list_item,                 // Your row layout for a child
            new String[] { "Site_Name" },                      // Field(s) to use from group cursor
            new int[] { R.id.lblListHeader },                 // Widget ids to put group data into
            new String[] { "Day_Name" },          // Field(s) to use from child cursors
            new int[] { R.id.lblListItem });          // Widget ids to put child data into

    elv.setAdapter(madapter);                         // set the list adapter.
}

public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
    public MyExpandableListAdapter(Cursor cursor, Context context,int groupLayout,
                                   int childLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, String[] childrenFrom,
                                   int[] childrenTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo,
                childLayout, childrenFrom, childrenTo);
    }
    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        Cursor childCursor = mHelper.fetchChildren(groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex("id_room")));
        startManagingCursor(childCursor);
        childCursor.moveToFirst();
        return childCursor;
    }
```

Comment: Show your code snippets, so we can make sense of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I add it, but I only I want the cursor to go throw child elements, how can I make parent element static? and a user has the availability to choose available parent "category" for their added child element